# How to open isolated popup on GCM notification like Viber

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Generally upon receiving message using Android GCM we call generateNotfication that fires a notification.

I want to know that instead of firing a notification in notification bar, I would like to open an isolated popup window, where user can perform further actions as Viber do.

As for viber, No matter where ever a user is, upon receiving a text message it open a smart popup dialog where you can reply.

Why i call it isolated, because i don't the whole application to launch, just an activity in the form of modal box.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you can do it, on receiving a message from GCM, launch a transparent activity and from within the activity, you create and show a dialog inside `onCreate()`. Then when a user presses `Cancel` button, you can call `finish()` to close the `Activity` . See here: 
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) . This way to user it would feel that you have just created a dialog and in actual you would be creating a transparent activity.